# angular upload, need to send file size in content disposition

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers

**Background**:
I have an AngularJS front end uploading files to an ASP.NET backend. I have a custom MultipartStreamProvider that is persisting the data to Azure. The only problem I have now is that the existing angular code is not submitting the file size, only the filename in the content disposition header

```
MyMultipartFormDataStreamProvider : MultipartStreamProvider
{
    // ...
    public override Stream GetStream(HttpContent parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
    {
        // For form data, Content-Disposition header is a requirement
        ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = headers.ContentDisposition;
        if (contentDisposition != null)
        {
            // create default filename if its missing
            contentDisposition.FileName = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName) ? $"{Guid.NewGuid()}.data" : contentDisposition.FileName);
            var size = contentDisposition.Size;  // This is null right now!
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the angular code

```
        $scope.$watch('files', function (files) {
        $scope.formUpload = false;
        console.log(files);
        if (files != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                $scope.errorMsg = null;
                (function (file) {
                    file.size = 25;
                    upload(file);
                })(files[i]);
            }
        }
    });

    function upload(file) {
        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: window.location.origin + "/api/mydocs/uploadfile?clientFolder=" + $scope.attachmentFolder + "&clientId=" + $scope.clientId + "&userId=" + $scope.currentUser.UserId,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {},
            fields: {},
            file: file

        });
```

**Question**:

How can I make Angular include the file size in the Content Disposition Header?

Thanks!

Comment: Please change the question tag to angularjs, angular tag is used for angular 2+

Comment: @Dan Csharpster, Curious if you figured this out. I'm having the same issue where sending a request from Postman results in a null for Size property.

Comment: I issued a hack for now. In the headers: {} section, I was able to put file-info as a key and then file.name + "-" +file.value

Comment: Here's the code change I made on the client side: headers: { 'file-info':file.name + "-/" + file.size },   and on the backend, I just parse that value out and hand the size value to the component that needs it.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this file upload directive in the past with great success. It will return the file size on the client side once your file is processed by the directive.

[ngFileUpload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  However, I may have not been clear. I don't need the file size returned to the client side. I need the client side to send the file size to the server, so in ASP.NET I can allocate enough memory for it. I may be able to just grab the file out of the request and calculate the size that way, but that is not how this class I'm using works by default.

Comment: Can it also send that data along with the request?